# A generic is making my decode function throw an error

Tags: json, swift, generics, types

```
do {
    let thing = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginAndVerify.self, from: data ?? Data())
    if thing is genericType {
        print("it is the type...")
    }
    print(genericType.Type.self)
    //simpleResponse = SimpleResponse(success: <#T##Int#>, message: <#T##String?#>, url: <#T##String?#>)
    print("WE DID IT")
} catch let err {
    print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Initially, I tried using `decode(genericType.self` but that threw an error and I reached `line 10`.   This code prints out `"LoginAndVerify.type"` for `line 6` but doesn't print for `line 4`.  Why is that?  If the compiler recognizes the type of `genericType` as `LoginAndVerify.type`, and `thing` is of type `LoginAndVerify`, shouldn't `line 4` print?  Why would `decode(genericType.self` not work? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], some code that I can copy and paste into a playground to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I can try...sure